# Firestore query on Python with macos hangs forever and get 504 Deadline Exceeded #787

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
`    from google.cloud import firestore
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
# Path to your service account JSON key
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./alien-lattice-<some path>.json"
# Initialize Firestore client
db = firestore.Client(project="alien-lattice-403320")
print(db)
# Add data
doc_ref = db.collection("users").document("alovelace")
doc_ref.set({"first": "Ada", "last": "Lovelace", "born": 1815})`
```

I am running the above code to get started as my backend. I used the right service account and       then it just hangs forever without being able to get or set the document. There is no other   message. What might be the problem.

I am running on Python 3.11 with macos Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)

I tried to use new project still no luck